# Create an event with a stored procedure and table variable name

Tags: mysql, events, stored-procedures

On a weekly basis I would like to copy all data from the past week and insert it into a table (with the week number included in the table name) in an other database.

This works fine using a stored procudure:

```
SET @weekno:=WEEKOFYEAR(NOW());
SET @sql_text = concat('INSERT INTO 
archive.data_2017_week_',@weekno,'  select * from live.data_archive where 
year(time) = 2017 AND week(time) = ',@weekno,'');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql_text;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

However if i try to make a weekly event for this in phpMyAdmin I get MySQL 'Error Code: 1064'.

Is it possible to run a prepared statement in an event?

If not, is there a better method to copy weekly data to a table with the week number included in it's name?

Many Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to use multiple, separate tables? The overhead of using a single should be minimal if you've indexed it properly. If you need to distribute the data across different block devices (and can't use LVM/RAID) then you can use partitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply create a stored procedure as shown below code

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `YOUR_PROCEDURE`()
BEGIN
    SET @weekno:=WEEKOFYEAR(NOW());
    SET @sql_text = concat('INSERT INTO 
                            archive.data_2017_week_',@weekno,'  select * from live.data_archive where 
                            year(time) = 2017 AND week(time) = ',@weekno,'');
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql_text;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

And then call that procedure using event as shown in below code.

For basics about it you can check here [MySQL Events and Time Duration](https://www.sitepoint.com/working-with-mysql-events/).

```
CREATE EVENT YOUR_EVENT_NAME
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 week
    DO
      CALL YOUR_PROCEDURE();
```

Comment: are you confirming prepared statements are not allowed in events?

Comment: @P.Salmon Not sure,but i had tried same and it's not working for me.
Also i had check with this https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?119,573071,573071